# Smarty and OOP within a compiled tpl

Tags: arrays, oop, smarty

```
$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['Variable']->value
```

I wonder how smarty accesses objects. smarty_tpl is the object, but what is the property in the code example of a compiled tpl? Is it the array `tpl_vars` or `value` or a mixture of both?

In php, I create a smarty object and use it with methods (e.g. assign and display).
In the template itself (file .tpl) i do not use OOP, but a procedural style like in html.

Comment: I found another example:     $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['SearchTop5']->value[$_smarty_tpl->getVariable('smarty')->value['section']['i']['index']]['Value'] Here, three arrows are used to access what ? In this case, 'value' is an array, in the first example, it was a string ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, are you trying to access a variable assigned to smarty from within PHP? not the template file itself? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your message beforehand regarding the isset and the notices. my idea in this question regarding the tpl_vars is to understand smarty. I dont want to access smarty variables inside php. I just want to know what the statement `$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['Variable']->value`does because I never saw anything similar to it in oop. It seems to me that properties and arrays are mixed ?

Comment: This syntax, $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['Variable']->value, means that $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['Variable'] is an object, so $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars is an array of objects, which is quite usual

Comment: It is not so clear for me, can you explain it with other words ? I suppose that $smartytpl is the object, and $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars is the array with the index tpl_vars ? What would be another index ? Could it also be a numeric indes like $smarty_tpl->0 ?

Comment: no, PHP does not support this syntax. See my answer for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to make a small example, that will hopefully make this syntax clear to you:

```
//A class that represents a fruit basket, a collection of fruits. Similar to $smarty, which is a collection of variables (among other things)
class FruitBasket
{
    public $basket = array();

    public function foo() {

    }
}
//A class that represents a fruit. It has some properties, like 'name' and 'color' 
class Fruit
{
    public $name = null;
    public $color = null;

    public function __construct($fruit_name) {
        $this->name = $fruit_name;
    }
}

$fruits = array();  //Make an array that will hold various fruits

$fruit = new Fruit('banana');   //Create a fruit
$fruit->color = 'yellow';       //Assign a value to its 'color' property 
$fruits['banana'] = $fruit;     //Assign the fruit to the 'fruits' array

//Make the same steps for 2 more fruits
$fruit = new Fruit('apple');
$fruit->color = 'red';
$fruits['apple'] = $fruit;

$fruit = new Fruit('pear');
$fruit->color = 'green';
$fruits['pear'] = $fruit;

$fruit_basket = new FruitBasket(); //Create a new fruit basket
$fruit_basket->basket = $fruits; //Assign the $fruits array to its 'basket' property

echo $fruit_basket->basket['banana']->color;    //prints 'yellow'
```

Comment: good example that shows how to access an array element and its property. Accepted the answer.